# is there a library that sticks a zoom in/out button over an image and allows incremental + and -

Tags: javascript, html, image, zooming

is there any library or component that allows photoshop or pdf style zooming where i have images that i want users to be able to click to zoom in and out and i want to support being able to zoom in a number of times and zoom out a number of times

i want the equivalent of every user having the ability to do stuff like this:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/139

Comment: out of curiosity, why did you let it auto accept the answer? not only it only gives half of the bounty but you also lose your voice for saying which answer you prefer

Comment: hmm . . i didnt realize it gave 1/2 the bounty . . apologies

Comment: Well 1/2 of the bounty is unfortunate but not a real problem. However you can't change an auto accepted answer for a bounty while you can for an answer to a normal question

Comment: i didn't realize that either . . i dont understand the logic of not being able to change an auto accepted answer.  you have paid your bounty, why create new restrictions ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at:

- the jQuery [gzoom](http://lab.gianiaz.com/jquery/gzoom/) plugin
- [shiftzoom](http://www.netzgesta.de/shiftzoom/) (example [here](http://www.netzgesta.de/shiftzoom/caribbean.html))
- the jQuery [MapBox](http://wayfarerweb.com/jquery/plugins/mapbox/) plugin (works with scroll whell and I'm sure you can stick + / - buttons)
- the [MooZom](http://www.rborn.info/moozoom.php) plugin (works with scroll whell and I'm sure you can stick + / - buttons)
- [Anything Zoomer](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingZoomer/image.php) is also nice

Then, there is [Zoomorama](http://www.zoomoblog.com/zooming/2009/09/operational-sidetoside-comparaison-with-seadragon.html) which is  an alternative to [Microsoft's Seadragon](http://www.seadragon.com/developer/ajax/) if you don't mind using flash.

Answer (score 10):

You can use **Google Maps API** to do that. All you need to do is to generate [custom map tiles](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#Custom_Map_Types). There is a [nice tutorial here](http://forevermore.net/articles/photo-zoom/).

**EDIT**: Just found another [site](http://www.casa.ucl.ac.uk/software/googlemapimagecutter.asp) that uses the same technique.

I have also found some alternative solutions that are not based on Google Maps API (1st is the best in my opinion):

1. **[Microsoft's Seadragon](http://www.seadragon.com/developer/ajax/)**
2. http://ditchnet.org/dhtmlgallery/slider.html
3. http://www.oneblackbear.com/zoom/index.html
4. http://www.rborn.info/moozoom.php

and other questions about this topic:

1. [Image Zoom using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194761/image-zoom-using-javascript)
2. [Javascript for zooming and panning an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626558/javascript-for-zooming-and-panning-an-image)
3. [Javascript / jQuery image zoom plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972378/javascript-jquery-image-zoom-plugin)

**EDIT:** If you have really large images, you can upload the files to [GigaPan(SM)](http://www.gigapan.org/) and [embed](http://www.gigapan.org/embedding/) them in your website.

Comment: I think using the Google Maps API for this is a great idea in general, but total overkill for the task at hand (adding a + and - button to an image). On the other hand, the OP may like it. We'll see.

Comment: @Pekka It may be a overkill indeed, but Google Maps API is reliable, well documented and lightweight.

Comment: @Gaby Which one of the proposed solutions?

Comment: btw, no -1 but I also find using google maps api for that is overkill

Comment: I would not dare say it's overkill if I don't know the size of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at GWT too...

here is a zoomer made in GWT: 
http://gwtgallery.appspot.com/about_app?app_id=21025

Comment: i am confused on this one.  Do you have to use some seperate service here or can you simply get the source code and embed it on your website.  it seems like you need to pay and register for some server side service

Answer (score 1):

[Silverlight Deep Zoom](http://silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/deepzoom/) is one cool way if your environment permits it.

Here's a kind of overkill example of it : http://memorabilia.hardrock.com/

Also from a  [Flash](http://theflashblog.com/?p=351) advocate. And [some more stuff](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeepZoomSeadragonSilverlight2MultiScaleImagesAtMix.aspx) - and maybe most fun of all a [13 gigapixel image](http://www.harlem-13-gigapixels.com/).